# Delayed Data Insertion In MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, session, http-post

I'm trying to insert data in the `cart table` but something really fishy is happening... First there is a a huge delay between the time I click on "add to cart" and the moment I actually see the data in the cart table. Second, I cannot add multiple items at the same time. Everything seems to be okay as  the script fire up the success message. But when I run the `add_cart.php` individually, I see this `?` at the top of the page.

**add_cart.php**

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MyProjectName/core/init.php'; 
$product_id = isset($_POST['product_id'])? sanitize($_POST['product_id']):' ';
$size = isset($_POST['size'])? sanitize($_POST['size']):' ';
$available = isset($_POST['available'])? sanitize($_POST['available']):' ';
$quantity  = isset($_POST['quantity'])? sanitize($_POST['quantity']):' ';
$item = array(); 
$item[] = array(
    'id'            => $product_id, 
    'size'         => $size, 
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'available' => $available, 
    ); 
$domain =($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '{$product_id}'"); 
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['prod_name']. ' was added to your cart.'; 

//check if the cart cookie exists
if (is_array($cart_id != ' ')) {
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'"); 
$cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ); 
$previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true); 
$item_match = 0; 
$new_items = array(); 

foreach($previous_items as $pitem){
    if ($item[0]['id'] == $pitem['id'] && $item[0]['size'] == $pitem['size']) {
        $pitem['quantity'] = $pitem['quantity'] + $item[0]['quantity']; 

if ($pitem['quantity'] > $available) {
    $pitem['quantity'] = $available; 

} 
$item_match = 1; 
} 
$new_items[] = $pitem; 
}

if ($item_match != 1) {
    $new_items = array_merge($item,$previous_items); 
} 

$items_json = json_encode($new_items); 
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days")); 
$db->query("UPDATE cart SET items = '{$items_json}', expire_date = '{$cart_expire}' WHERE id = '{cart_id}'"); 
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false); 
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false); 

}else{ 
// add to databse and set cookie
    $items_json = json_encode($item); 
    $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
    $db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}')"); 
    $cart_id = $db->insert_id; 
    setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false); 


}
?>
```

**init.php**

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "mydatabasename");
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "database failed to connect with following errors:". mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MyProjectName/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';

$cart_id = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){
    $cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
}



if(isset($_SESSION['SBUser'])){
    $user_id = $_SESSION['SBUser'];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='$user_id ' ");
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $fn = explode(' ', $user_data['full_name']);
    $user_data['first'] = $fn[0];
        $user_data['last'] = $fn[1];
}



if(isset($_SESSION['success_flash'])){
    echo '<div class="bg-success"><p class="text-success text-center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';
    unset($_SESSION['success_flash']);
}


if(isset($_SESSION['error_flash'])){
    echo '<div class="bg-danger"><p class="text-danger text-center">'.$_SESSION['error_flash'].'</p></div>';
    unset($_SESSION['error_flash']);
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot more secure to use SESSIONS rather than COOKIES to store your cart_id. You do realise that I can edit cookies on my browser and enter any cart_id I fancy

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I read the document. Thanks for that. My problem is now solved.